# How can I decide which emails go through SMTP relay?

Tags: postfix, smtp, sendgrid

I am using postfix configuration that use SMTP relay on Sendgrid service like this:

```
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
header_size_limit = 4096000
relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:587
```

And it works fine for all emails that are sent from my domain. But there is another scenario that we use:

Users in my domain can are using email forwarding instead of POP3 to push emails they receive in mydomain.com to their gmail.com accounts. And I don't want those email to go through Sendgrid, but rather to be forwarded directly to gmail.

To summarize - I want emails that have *to* field set to *@mydomain.com to be sent directly and all other emails to go through SMTP relay on Sendgrid service, but in current  configuration they all go through Sendgrid.

Can I configure it to work this way?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a transport table.

http://www.postfix.org/transport.5.html